# ffmpeg: cut video but getting the wrong length

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to cut a video.
Here is the input information:

```
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5113 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
```

And this is the command I use:

```
    ffmpeg -y -ss 10 -t 5 -i test.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

But the output duration is about 9.66 seconds.

It worked when I removed the '-c copy' option or the input doesn't contain the 'tv, bt709' tag. But it's slower.

I wonder how I can use '-c copy' and get the right piece of video I need?

Comment: I was wrong. The input without 'tv, by709' tag still doesn't work.

Comment: Codec copy can only spice on key frames.

Answer (score 10):

In my situation, I don't use `-c copy` but still receive an incorrect duration. Upon investigation, I found that it caused by "video chapters". So disable chapters by `-map_chapters -1` will output the correct duration.

```bash
ffmpeg -ss 04:20 -to 04:41 -i "$input_file" -c:a aac -c:v h264_videotoolbox -b:v 29445k -map_chapters -1 "output.mp4"
```

```
-ss 04:20              : From
-to 04:41              : To
-i "$input_file"       : Input file
-c:a aac               : Set AAC codec for audio output
-c:v h264_videotoolbox : h264 hw encoder on Mac
-b:v 29445k            : Output video bitrate
-map_chapters -1       : Disable video chapters
"output.mp4"           : Output file
```

Comment: Thank you, would never had guessed that by myself.

Answer (score 2):

**The first command will cut from 00:01:00 to 00:03:00 (in the original), using the faster seek.**

**The second command will cut from 00:01:00 to 00:02:00, as intended, using the slower seek.**

**The third command will cut from 00:01:00 to 00:02:00, as intended, using the faster seek.**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy cut.mp4

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -c copy cut.mp4

ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy -copyts cut.mp4
```

Full document [enter link description here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)

Comment: This seems to be a more common root cause than the map_chapters, interesting to see placement of options being so impactful!

Answer (score 0):

from the ffmpeg documentation:

> -t duration (input/output) When used as an input option (before -i), limit the duration of data read from the input file.
>
> When used as an output option (before an output url), stop writing the
>   output after its duration reaches duration.
>
> duration must be a time duration specification, see (ffmpeg-utils)the
>   Time duration section in the ffmpeg-utils(1) manual.

Given this, if you want a 5 seconds video stream try to specify the duration you want to read from the input file (before the -i tag) and the duration you want from your final output file (before the output url)

Comment: I used 'ffmpeg -ss 10 -t 5 -i test.mp4 -t 5 output.mp4'. The duration was right, but the output doesn't match the 10 to 15 seconds of the input which is what I want.

Comment: This might interest you, there are a lot of caveat when cutting content: [https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read it. Tried several ways though, it just doesn't work when doing codec copy and want it to be fast...

Answer (score 0):

just delete -c copy and you will get the exact cut.

"ffmpeg -y -ss 10 -t 5 -i test.mp4 output.mp4"